# ERC-20 Token Transfer Error

Tags: metamask, myetherwallet

No matter how much gas I use, I get this error :
ERC-20 Token Transfer Error (Unable to locate Corresponding Transfer Event Logs), Check with Sender.

When I try to transfer tokens managed through this contract :  0xc72fe8e3dd5bef0f9f31f259399f301272ef2a2d

You can see different instances with these TxHash :
0x9ad5259ab5a1b908257b86902a58af5506806bbabf942462b99c99b53a56791b
0x26a0f3a6bab4e7ec0908aa8216edbb8c9157b90c6d4906b8aac0569fbc2afd8f
0xb2809be5f3fb4834b88364ef528100cc1ff0251414c3aff0749cf2834676c368
0x67a4139a6ef42b7936404c4b5681d36ce52626979801a3a7f990b7c2b59ae653
0x6c754515ee6a75d3b622fa41637265202bcd3c6a246695b712fed52cc7ae09fd
0x6b57e2e9532311ff5c2c42b3543f60f0a3d3a012be9a05363625dcc7db64df48
0x059aa3f763f918956622fbabe943b791d6297e1ea88f95cbac6131f28c905ca0
0x0650801cd4b6a861c521d8df58a854a35d08492afb9d3316db1240879c898150
0x464d787564589600ed2cbc83f13d7967ce7829f0a261abfd17d0e5b6493826af
0x4a843fc710bcad3332c18f2a41249cbf6a84bcdaa61f17306d6077ef3c588a49
0xbbb201fbc58a8c41a53f3d46011c2f6cfb723fa76ad5f0abff26dbc32289f607

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the code](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc72fe8e3dd5bef0f9f31f259399f301272ef2a2d#code):

```
function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
    require(value <= balances[msg.sender] - lockedBalanceOf(msg.sender));
    return super.transfer(to, value);
}
```

`balances[0x7530e7a3cfae3ee4a4220f65cae06f08cb837e66]` is `9014007215564423376800`, and `lockedBalanceOf[0x7530e7a3cfae3ee4a4220f65cae06f08cb837e66]` is `121000000000000000000`.

So `balances[msg.sender] - lockedBalanceOf[msg.sender] == 8893007215564423376800`. The first transaction hash you shared—I didn't check the others—is attempting to transfer an `amount` of `9000000000000000000000`, which is a lot larger than the allowed amount.

I don't know anything else about this token (like what `lockedBalanceOf` means), so I don't know what you should do to "unlock" that balance. I just know why this transaction was reverted.

Comment: Thank you so much! These contract errors are very far from being verbose as a user.